# Maximize the distance

Tags: performance, distance, maximize

can you give me a hint to this problem? I have a vector of int sorted ascending and the distance between two elements is v[i+1] - v[i]. For example v[]={0 , 5, 7 ,8, 10}, distance between 5 and 0 is 5, 7 and 5 is 2 etc.I want to remove NB values (NB is number of values that i want to remove) of this vector (i can't remove 0 or 10 so NB could be maximum 3) so that the distance between two elements would be maximum. For this example the minimum distance is between 7 and 8...if i want to remove only one element (NB=1) I would remove 8, than the minimum distance would be 2 (distance between 5 and 7).

I made a structure smth like this: (0,5, diff 5) (5,7 diff 2) (7,8 diff 1) (8,10 diff 2) then i sorted this ascending by diff and as long as NB is not 0 i would remove the second element from the pair if it's not 10 or 0, find the next pair which has that element, replace it with the first element from the pair when i first found that element,and then update diff...In this example i will remove 8 and the result would be (5,7 diff 2) (7,10 diff 3) (0,5, diff 5). I think this is very inefficient because i have to search again the element. Can u give me an idea of how to make this efficient?

Comment: "NB values?" Please clarify.

Comment: 0 and 10 are the lowest and highest, it might mean non-boundary.

Comment: NB is the number of values that i want to remove